# Code isn't continuing to next input once finding days in file aka hold.txt PYTHON3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I'm having problems with my code my goal is to create a task assigner for days of the week as in a routine. Yes, I could do this a lot easier I know but I'm choosing to use files and such other ways on purpose. (no its not a school assignment)
Code works fine
I have a feeling the following code

```
import os
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")#this code is in a way reseting the output but all values remain if im not mistaken is just scrolls up and down
#doesn't need import os except once. Also I have a feeling this code abovee is messing with my code but I dont know for sure and I need it or a alt
```

[here](https://replit.com/join/kouoojjs-brocktempler)
is a link to my code it's not a lot.
Problem:
My code gets added to list that goes into file on seperate lines and yes that does work then the user is told to do certain things and after they are done they are redirected to home page(def main():) Then the user is told to enter certain things again except obviously different day which you will get when you read the code. But on when redirected to home page and user inputs a day it does nothing even when my code is being put into file and seems to be read and the code is set to when user inputs a day and it goes into file and if read what user gave then code is suppose to continue. But again once redirected and user inputs day nothing happens.

-STILL LEARNING THE ROPES OF THIS COOL SITE!
-edit heres the full code cause some people cannot sign in to replit.

```
lst = []


def main():
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        days = [
            "sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday",
            "saturday"
        ]
        str = "Welcome To Task Assigner!"
        print(str.center(61, '-'))
        str = ""
        print(str.center(122, '-'))
        answered = False
        while answered == False:
            userInput = input(
                "\nWhat day of the week would you like to assign a event: \n")
            user = userInput
            global lst
            lst = []

            user = userInput.lower().split()
            for word in user:
                if word in days:
                    lst.append(word)
                    # set answered to True boolean
                    print(lst)
                    with open('hold.txt', 'a') as f:
                        for day in lst:
                            f.write(day + '\n')

                    answered = True

            # only evaulated after reviewing all words, if True is not set, prompts user again and let's them know that their answer is not valid
            if answered == False:
                print("You typed a day of week wrong! Try Again!")


main()

import os
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")#this code is in a way reseting the output but all values remain if im not mistaken is just scrolls up and down

whatReturn = 'monday'
f = open('hold.txt', 'r')
h = f.readlines()

for line in h:
    pass  # This is extra code

mondayAssign = ''

line = ''

#asking user for task
def monday(h):
    for line in h:
        if whatReturn in line:
            global mondayAssign
            mondayAssign = input("Assign a task for Monday: "
                                 )  # to use "line" you must first define it
            break
        else:
            pass


monday(h)

yea = "yes"
na = "no"
mondayAdd = ""


def mondayy(h):
    for line in h:
        if whatReturn in line:
            global mondayAdd
            mondayAdd = input(
                "Anything else you would like to add, 'yes' or 'no': ")
        if yea in mondayAdd:
            global mondayDoubleAssign
            mondayDoubleAssign = input("Assign another task for Monday: ")
            break
        elif na in mondayAdd:
            pass


mondayy(h)
lst = []
if yea in mondayAdd:#sending user back to def main() homescreen to then go onto to assign more days to have tasks
    try:
        print("\nTasks for Monday:\n", mondayAssign, '\n', mondayDoubleAssign)
    except:
        na in mondayAdd
        pass
if yea in mondayAdd:
    inputChoice = input("\nType 'e' for main menu: \n")
    'e' in inputChoice
    main()
elif na in mondayAdd:
    inputChoice = input("\nType 'e' for main menu: \n")
    'e' in inputChoice
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
    main()
#good chance that the os.system code abovee is messing with code
whatReturn = "tuesday"
tuesdayAssign = ''
def tuesday(h):
    for line in h:
        if whatReturn in line:
            global tuesdayAssign
            tuesdayAssign = input("Assign a task for Tuesday: "
                                  )  # to use "line" you must first define it
            break
        else:
            pass


tuesday(h)

yea = "yes"
na = "no"
tuesdayAdd = ""


def tuesdayy(h):
    for line in h:
        if whatReturn in line:
            global tuesdayAdd
            tuesdayAdd = input(
                "Anything else you would like to add, 'yes' or 'no': ")
        if yea in tuesdayAdd:
            global tuesdayDoubleAssign
            tuesdayDoubleAssign = input("Assign another task for Tuesday: ")
            break
        elif na in tuesdayAdd:
            pass


tuesdayy(h)

if yea in tuesdayAdd:
    try:
        print("\nTasks for Tuesday:\n", tuesdayAssign, '\n',
              tuesdayDoubleAssign)
    except:
        na in tuesdayAdd
        pass
if yea in tuesdayAdd:
    inputChoice = input("\nType 'e' for main menu: \n")
    'e' in inputChoice
    main()
elif na in tuesdayAdd:
    inputChoice = input("\nType 'e' for main menu: \n")
    'e' in inputChoice
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
    main()
```

Comment: I think one problem is you used a link to your code rather than posting it, plus the link requires a login. If the code is "not a lot" then just post it [formatted!!!].

Comment: I can't access the link to your code, anyway it should be posted in the question instead of linked. Can you please post the code in the question?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort and submit data to be used to reproduce your problem. While providing an image is helpful, it doesn't allow for reproducing the issue. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Comment: I didn't provide an image, itsproh66.

Comment: @C.Peck  posted code above hope fully works out

Comment: @Kevin done and done posted codee

Answer (score 0):

OK, I had to reformat the code so I could figure out the actual code-flow.

No, the `os.system` calls you were concerned about are not the cause of the problem.

What you are missing is a "master loop" where the user is returned back to the prompt [presumably with some sort of 'exit' option].

Here is your current codeflow (simplified):

1. prompt user to enter day-of-week
2. [if monday] do 'monday' processing.
3. prompt user to enter day-of-week
4. [if tuesday] do 'tuesday' processing.
5. prompt user to enter day-of-week

That's it. Once the call to `main()` at the end of tuesday processing returns, the program ends.

In other words, calling `main()` *doesn't* start back at the beginning again, it merely executes the code inside the `main` function.

A "master loop" might work something like this, in pseudo-code:

```
quit=False
while not quit:
    main() # might set quit to True
    if quit:
        break #end of program
    <check for adding a task for Monday>
    <check for adding a task for Tuesday>
    <check for adding a task for Wednesday>
    <repeat for thursday-sunday>
```

This way, until the user says to exit, they will continually be prompted for a day, and they can add a task for that day. You don't want to call `main` inside each day's code, just fall through, and let the loop re-prompt the user.

Comment: So the code you provided should be inserted at lines 161 and 166?

Comment: I put the given script on lines 161,166 and did the same thing to monday's code and for that section its the same thing code got closer than it has at least but then kept looping main() after inputing a day of week.

Comment: The code you posted is only 159 lines long, so we're no longer on the same page. Working with your original post, the "master loop" replaces lines 40-159. Move your various functions to before main(). Do _not_ call main() as you currently do at lines 100,105,153, and 158: the loop calls main().

Comment: Wait you just said to move my other functions to before main(). I am proable interpeting this wrong but then the loop you gave me                                                                                           ```while not quit:
      main() # might set quit to True
      if quit:
        break #end of program```

Comment: except with you know actually indented correctley. I'm gonna send you a forked link of my code you can adjust whatever you want then send the link back to me https://replit.com/join/kouoojjs-brocktempler